# $location.search is not working - angular 1.6.4

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

This is my URL :

```
http://localhost:8091/apps/dashboard/#!/#%2Findex%3Fsession=564badc5919b42fa880f1b34ae5d0740
```

I am getting 'undefined' from the below mentioned code:

```
 $location.search().session
```

What is wrong here ? I am new with Angular and wanted to get session variable from the query string.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

It is required to include **$locationProvider** in your app.config. 
Then, you need to configure html5Mode before using $location.search(). 
Below sample will help you.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, 
$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : 'xxx.html'
            ,  controller: 'xxxController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Figured the construction of my URL was incorrect. Re-constructed the URL and all started working as expected.

For me , this was the correct URL format :

```
http://localhost:8091/apps/SPMDashboardApp/#!/index?session==564badc5919b42fa880f1b34ae5d0740
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as well:

> Since AngularJS provides the query string as a set of key/value pairs,
>   use something like this:

URL - http://my.site.com/?myparam=33

```
if ( $location.search().hasOwnProperty( 'myparam' ) ) {
   var myvalue = $location.search()['myparam'];
   // 'myvalue' now stores '33'
}
```

> You must inject $location into your Controller.

It’s easy to forget because there are two locations (like all injections):

```
app.controller( 'MyController', [ '$scope', '$location', function( $scope, $location )
```

You must add a ‘base’ element to your HTML. (very important when your application goes to production)

> This line is necessary to support $location HTML5 mode (for query
>   string parameters).

```
<base href="/">
```